# Coulomb energy in VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

In DFT, the Coulomb energy is defined as the sum of Hartree energy, nuclear-electron attraction, and nuclear-nuclear repulsion. In VASP output, we can find the Hartree energy, and also the nuclear-nuclear repulsion (sum of alpha Z and Ewald energy). My question is, how to get the nuclear-electron attraction term?

Comment: Did you get the Coulomb energy from the output?

Comment: @Camps The output contains a number of different energies, including the ones mentioned in the post. But there is no "Coulomb energy" in the output. Also, as asked here, it is not clear where to find the nuclear-electron attraction term.

Comment: The nuclear-electron interaction (really Kohn-Sham particles, not electrons) is modelled with the pseudopotential, so the relevant energies are the local and non-local pseudopotential terms. However, pseudopotentials introduce arbitrary level-shifts in your eigenenergies, so depending on what you're doing you may need to correct the results somehow. Also note that this neglects the core electrons.

Comment: Was the comment by Phil useful? Can you let us know what remains to be answered for you? Are you still working on this? Please update us!

Comment: @NikeDattani Sorry for my delay in response, as I just noticed your message. I think Phil's answer is very helpful. As the reference for eigenenergies is ambiguous, I'm not using the Coulomb energy explicitly now.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is your question still a problem for you? Have you moved on with your research now?

Comment: @NikeDattani This question is not a problem anymore for me. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1):

The OP has said in [this comment](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9141/coulomb-energy-in-vasp?noredirect=1#comment22703_9141) that the problem is no longer a concern, this Community Wiki answer serves to remove the question out of the unanswered queue, but without closing it in case someone wants to write a better answer. If you do write a better answer, you can leave a comment on this one and I will delete this one :)